# App Store keeps asking me to type in verification code after password, but I'm receiving no verification code

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

The title is the question. I only own a MacBook and whenever I try to log in to the App Store I get the message: "An Apple ID verification code is required to sign in. Type your password followed by the verification code shown on your other devices."

I'm not sure what this means. If the message makes sense, shouldn't I have received a text message on my (Android) phone that's connected to my Apple ID?

I'm able to log in to my Apple ID on the website perfectly fine. What am I supposed to do here?

The OS that I'm using is Mavericks btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you have enabled 2-factor authentication on your Apple-ID (which is a good thing). Mavericks was created before this 2-factor authentication method was available for Apple-IDs and thus do not know about it. In order to still support logging in from Mavericks, you have to enter not only your password in the password field, but your password followed by the 2-factor verification code (6 digits).

The verification code is shown automatically on trusted devices (such as iPhones, iPads and Macs). If you haven't got a trusted device and are logging in through a web site, an iOS device or a recent macOS version, you'll be able to choose to have the verification sent as a text message or voice call. However, if you only have your Mavericks Mac, it is too old to support that feature.

I would suggest upgrading your macOS version to the latest possible version. 2-factor authentication is fully supported with Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11). Your MacBook running Mavericks should be fully capable of running El Capitan as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that when I log in to my Apple ID on the website, I have an option for using my phone to receive the code. But, like you said, since Mavericks doesn't support that I don't see that option. Concatenating the verification code I received on my phone to my password doesn't work. Should I have logged out, and used the verification code I received on a new login attempt?

Comment: Just to add the reason why I'm trying to log in to App Store is because apparently for older versions of OS X you have to download the upgrades from the App Store? I recently reset my MacBook and the only option to install OS X was Mavericks.

Comment: Yes, you cannot reuse an old code.

Comment: So this actually didn't work. What I did is I went to https://appleid.apple.com/ and tried to log in, switched the option to use my phone to receive the verification via text, and put those 6 digits at the back of my password when logging into App Store. It just shows me the message asking if I forgot my password.

Comment: Concatenating the digits at the end on the first go before I get the "You need verification code" message just results in an incorrect password error.

Comment: I managed to find an old iPad and when I pressed "Get verification code" and concatenated that generated string then it worked. What a hassle.

Comment: You cannot reuse codes from the web, you have to use a new code generated on an iOS device displayed on screen. This can then be used on any other iOS device to login.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I'm just curious what people without other iOS devices would have to do in this kind of situation.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the number of people running Mavericks and not having any other Mac device is extremely small. Never run Mavericks on an internet connected device, which it is if you’re logging on with Apple-IDs.

Comment: This works (2022) and saved me on an old MBP with Mavericks (10.9). Process for me was 1) attempt a login on the old device (e.g. OS X 10.9 App Store sign in) -- it will fail, that's expected 2) Get a sign-in alert on other Apple device(s) which support 2FA. Select allow and note the verification code. 3) Return to the older device, add that code to the end of your password and sign in 4) It should work! If it doesn't double check you entered everything correctly and didn't wait too long between receiving the code and trying again to sign in.